# Match only digits in square brackets in a javascript regex without matching previous word

Tags: javascript, regex

I've the following regex in javascript. I'm trying to match only the first number inside square brackets in a string, as i have to replace it.
This is my code.

```
var str = 'dgt_gallery_item[3][type]'; 
var res = str.match(/^\w+\[(\d+)\]/g);
var rep = str.replace(/^\w+\[(\d+)\]/g, 5 + 1);
```

The idea is match from start 1 or more alphanumeric chars, then [, then start capturing 1 or more digits, then ].

I checked on [regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/cE0wH4/6) and my code looks correct but when i test it in the browser, it also matches the first word. How can i skip it?

[image]

Comment: why not use `substr`, use `indexOf` to get position of square brackets then replace away

Comment: @depperm a regex looks cleaner in this case, and i don't know how many digits are present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
var rep = str.replace(/(?!\[)\d/, (5+1));
```

---

[Regex live here](https://regex101.com/r/cE0wH4/8).

Explaining:

```
(?!\[)   # the number must be preceded by one '[' character
         # without taking it
\d       # takes a one digit number .. 
         # you can use '\d+' to multiple digits number
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript regex engine does not support Look Behind, so you need to do a little tweak here:

```
var str = 'dgt_gallery_item[3][type]';
var res = str.match(/(^\w+)\[(\d+)\]/g);
var rep = str.replace(/(^\w+)\[(\d+)\]/g, function(combinedMatch, pattern1, pattern2) {
    return pattern1 + "[" + 6 + "]";
});
```

Output: dgt_gallery_item[6][type]